# rails 5 app generated with postgresql - what's my password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have created a Rails 5.0.2 app with postgres as the database, it all works fine in the development environment.

But when I try to test the app in the production environment (Still on my local machine) I just can't figure out what the password for the database is.
I see this error in the log:

> PG::ConnectionBad (FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myapp"

My database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Can I access the ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] somehow? Was I supposed to set it up when I created the app?

I realize this may be very trivial. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set it in postgres

Comment: rails has nothing to do with postgres password

Comment: I did try to access psql but then I was faced with the same problem, it asked me for a password... But thanks, I know where to look now.